# How would I be able to pipe multiple commands using this program? C++

Tags: c++, shell, pipe

I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50160844/7872119 solution to an assignment I currently have. Yet this is one of my first times working with pipes in C++. So I'm still relatively new to all this. I was curious, if I wanted to change this program to be able to handle multiple pipes, how exactly would I be able to count how many pipes there are? I understand the ptr variable is a token, yet don't the commands execute as they're parsed? How would I be able to count all the pipes prior to execution? I'm looking to be able to execute something like this torwards the end

```
cat text.txt | sort | tail -3 | grep thankyou
```

Comment: The answer is "parse the input properly into a object representing the pipeline". For starters, you could split on `|` characters and treat each element of the resulting list as a command in the pipeline.

Comment: The question header + content of it and reference provided in the question seems to be related to C++, removed C tag.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit more tricky than it seems at start. Few rules should be obeyed:

1. A pipe character cannot be followed by itself (otherwise they form the `||` operator).
2. Remember of escapes.

2a. Of which strings are the most evil ones.

Let's say, we could implement a partially functional version as

```cpp
std::string command{"cat text.txt | sort | tail -3 | grep thankyou"};
std::size_t count{};
for(auto pos = command.find_first_of("|\\\"'"); pos != command.npos;
         pos = command.find_first_of("|\\\"'", pos + 1))
{
    switch(command[pos]) {
        // a pipe char not followed by a pipe char is actually what we're looking for
        case '|': if(pos < command.size() - 1 && command[pos + 1] == '|')
                  {
                      ++pos; // ||
                  }
                  else ++count; // a real pipe
                  break
        // a plain one-char escape
        case '\\': ++pos;
                   break;
        case '\'': // iirc, there's no escape chars in singly-quoted strings
                   // skip until next '
                   pos = command.find('\'', pos + 1);
                   break;
        default: // a doubly-quoted string
                 pos = find_closing(command, pos);
    }
}
```

`find_closing` should consume quoted strings, if any.

```cpp
std::string::size_type find_closing(std::string const &cmd, std::size_t pos) {
    for(auto nxt = cmd.find_first_of("\"\\", pos + 1); nxt != cmd.npos;
             nxt = cmd.find_first_of("\"\\", nxt + 2))
    {
        if(cmd[nxt] == '"') return nxt; // unescaped closing double quote
    }
    return cmd.npos;
}
```

Might need some debugging.

This code does not handle very complicated cases, like `echo "$(echo 123 | sed 's/2/4/')"`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have this line in a `std::string`:

```
using Command = std::vector<std::string>;
using Pipeline = std::vector<Command>;

Pipeline p;
Command c;
std::istringstream iss(line);
while (true) {
  std::string token;
  iss >> token;
  if (iss.eof()) {
    // Nothing more to read. Push the last command to the pipeline, if any.
    if (!c.empty()) {
      p.push_back(c);
    }
    break;
  }

  if (token == '|') {
    // We saw a pipe. Push the current command to the pipeline and
    // start parsing a new one.
    p.push_back(c);
    c.clear();
  } else {
    // This is a regular part of a command
    c.push_back(token);
  }
}
```

At the end, `p` will have the following shape:

```
[
  ["cat", "text.txt"],
  ["sort"],
  ["tail", -3],
  ["grep", "thankyou"]
]
```