# Multiple Pipes, C++

Tags: c++, process, pipe

I've been stuck on an issue with my program and just hoping for any help at this point :(
or guidance towards the right direction. In my code, I'm implenting a mini shell in c++ where the user can pipe 2 or more processes together, yet an issue keeps coming up whenever I execute it. Only the first and last commands actually execute so say I run:

```
cat b.txt | sort | tail -2
```

only cat b.txt and tail -2 would execute.
Here is my attempt at the whole program, also referenced to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50160844/7872119) which helped me tremendously with the setup.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/utsname.h>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;



  //this variable will take in the line of input submitted by the user
  char buf[1024];

  //PIDs for the two child processes
  pid_t pid[300];
  

  //these will be use to check the status of each child in the parent process
  int  status;
  int  status2;
  
  int pid_num = 1;

  //initializes the pipe
  int pipeA[2] = {-1,-1};

  int g = 0;

void first_command(int pipeA[], char * command[], bool pipeExists){

  if(pipeExists){
    dup2(pipeA[1], 1);
    close(pipeA[0]);
  }
  
  // this will run command[0] as the file to execute, and command as the arg
  execvp(command[0], command);
  printf("Can not execute FIRST command, please enter a valid command \n");
  exit(127);
}

void other_command(int pipeA[], char * command0[], int index){

  dup2(pipeA[0], 0);
  close(pipeA[1]);

  execvp(command0[0], command0);
  printf("Can not execute SECOND command, please enter a valid command\n");
  exit(127);

}
  void main_func() {
    //stay inside the loop and keep asking the user for input until the user quits the program
    while (fgets(buf,1024,stdin) != NULL){
  
      //initialize a boolean to check if user wants to pipe something, set to false by default until we check with user
      bool pipeExists = false;

      //initialize this arrays to NULL so anything that store in them gets cleared out.
      //these arrays will hold the commands that the user wants to carry out.
  
      char * command[1024] = {NULL, NULL, NULL};
      char *command0[1024] = {NULL, NULL, NULL};
      char *command1[] = {NULL, NULL, NULL};
      char *command2[] = {NULL, NULL, NULL};
      char *command3[] = {NULL, NULL, NULL};
      
      char ** my_commands[] = {
        command0,
        command1,
        command2,
        command3,
        NULL
      };
                  

  
      //Important to delete mark the last byte as 0 in our input
      buf[strlen(buf) -1] = 0;
  
      //initialize this number to zero to start save the tokens at this index 
      int index = 0;
  
      //a char * to hold the token saved by strtok
      char * ptr;
      ptr = strtok(buf, " \"");

  
      //Loop through 'buf' and save tokens accordingly
      while(ptr != NULL){
      
  
        // if the user types exit at any moment, the program will exit gracefully and terminate 
        if(strcmp( ptr, "exit" ) == 0){
          exit(0);
          
        }
        

        //if ptr is equal to | user wants to pipe something and we change pipeExists to true
        if(strcmp( ptr, "|" ) == 0){
          pipeExists = true;
          index= 0;
          ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
          
        }
  
        //enter here while user doesnt want to user pipes
        if(!pipeExists){
          command[index] = ptr;
          ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
          index++;
        }
  
        //enter here if user want to use pipes
        if(pipeExists){
         command0[index] = ptr;
          ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");          
          index++;
                
        }
        g++;
        printf("%s %i\n", ptr, g);
      }
      
      for (int s = 0; my_commands[s] != NULL; s++) {
        cout << command0[s] << " \n" << endl;
      }
      //if pipes exists then initialize it
      if(pipeExists){
        pipe(pipeA);
      }
  
      //create first child
      if ((pid[0] = fork()) == 0) {
        //pass in the pipe, commands and pipe to function to execute
        first_command(pipeA, command, pipeExists);
      }
      else if(pid[0] < 0){
        //error with child
        cerr<<"error forking first child"<<endl;
      }
      // if pipe exists create a second process to execute the second part of the command
      if(pipeExists){
        for(int f = 0; my_commands[f] != NULL; f++) {
        //create second child 
          if ((pid[f] = fork()) == 0) {
            other_command(pipeA, command0, index);         
        }
          else if(pid[f] < 0){
          //error with second child
          cerr<<"error forking child "<< pid_num << endl;
          }
        }
      pid_num++;
      }
      //if the pipe was created then we close its ends
      if(pipeExists){
        for(int z = 0; z < pid_num; z++) {
          close(pipeA[z]);
        }
      }
      //wait for the first child that ALWAYS executes
      if ( (pid[0] = waitpid(pid[0], &status, 0)) < 0)
        cerr<<"error waiting for first child"<<endl;
  
      //wait for the second child but only if user wanted to created to use piping
      if(pipeExists){
        for(int j = 1; j < pid_num; j++) {      
          if ( (pid[j] = waitpid(pid[j], &status2, 0)) < 0){
            printf("Status: %d", pid[j]);
            cerr<<"error waiting for child " << j <<endl;
            }
            }            
        }
    pid_num = 1;
  }//endwhile
  
}
```

Comment: Does fork even work with C++? I'd argue for using std::async (or std::thread) and modern c++ classes as std::string.

Comment: yessir, it does

Comment: :) I see it working in your code, though, that's c+cout, not c++. Does it still work if you use a lot RAII classes, like fstream ...?

Comment: I'm not exactly too sure :(, I'm fairly new to all this in c++. I'm more of a python and java type of guy

Comment: In that case, I can suggest you to NOT use `char*` for a variable, use `std::string` instead and do `.c_str()` if you have to call a function that needs a char*. Will make your life much easier!

Comment: Also, please don't use global variables, and replace c-style arrays (ex: `pid_t pid[300]`) by std::vector (ex: std::vector<pid_t>)

Comment: Would probably be easier to use https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/process.html

Comment: @AlanBirtles is it a library i have to download?

Comment: Yes, https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/more/getting_started/index.html

Comment: @AlanBirtles We can't do that for this assignment :/